# A good way to insert a string before a regex match in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

What's a good way to do this?  Seems like I could use a combination of a few different methods to achieve what I want, but there's probably a simpler method I'm overlooking.  For example, the PHP function preg_replace will do this.  Anything similar in Ruby?

simple example of what I'm planning to do:

```
orig_string = "all dogs go to heaven"
string_to_insert = "nice "
regex = /dogs/

end_result = "all nice dogs go to heaven"
```

Comment: Is it suitable for your requirenents to replace 'dogs' to 'nice dogs'?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be done using Ruby's "gsub", as per:

http://railsforphp.com/2008/01/17/regular-expressions-in-ruby/#preg_replace

```
orig_string = "all dogs go to heaven"
end_result = orig_string.gsub(/dogs/, 'nice \0')
```

Comment: Hey it should be `orig_string.gsub(/dogs/, 'nice \\0')`

Answer (score 3):

```
result = subject.gsub(/(?=\bdogs\b)/, 'nice ')
```

The regex checks for each position in the string whether the entire word `dogs` can be matched there, and then it inserts the string `nice` there.

The word boundary anchors `\b` ensure that we don't accidentally match `hotdogs` etc.